# Mail function not working with survey

Tags: php, email, sendmail, survey

I'm trying to create a survey page with mail function. But when i try the code, it doesnt send anything, no error just a blank page. 
I'm new to coding in general so may be some major errors in my code, sorry for that. 
I tried many options on google but nothing worked out.

My code:

```
$to = "my-email@mail.com";
$subject = "Survey";
$name = "MyName";
$from = "my-2nd-email@mail.com";
$quest1 = $_POST['quest1'];
$quest2 = $_POST['quest2'];
$quest3 = $_POST['quest3'];
$message = $quest1 . " " . $quest2 . " " . $quest3;
if (mail ($to, $subject, $message")){
echo "
    <h2>Your message is sent!</h2> 
    <b>To:</b> $to
    <b>Subject:     Survey</b> 
    <b>Svar:</b>
    $quest1'<BR>
    $quest2<BR>
    $quest3<BR>";
}
else{
  echo "Error: Message not sent";    
}
?>
```

And HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Kontakt</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Survey</h2>
<form name="kontakt" method="post" action="formmail.php">
  <p><br>
    Question1?<br>
    <input name="quest1" type="text" value="" size="60">
  </p>
  <p>Question2?<br>
    <input name="quest2" type="text" value="" size="60">
 </p>
  <p>Question3?<br>
    <textarea name="quest3" cols="60" rows="2"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><br>
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit"
value="Send message">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set up the SMTP server, etc. in your PHP ini file? Or is this on a web host?

Comment: Use header "$headers = "From: example@example.com" . "\r\n" ."

Comment: @stefan i have corrected if condition in you code..review and accept it..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix this line:

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $message"))
```

to this

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $message))
```

There was an unwanted `"` character after the `$message`

You need also add `"` to your echo.

So it should be like this:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
    echo "<h2>Your message is sent!</h2> 
            <b>To:</b> $to
            <b>Subject:     Survey</b> 
            <b>Svar:</b>
            $quest1<BR>
            $quest2<BR>
            $quest3<BR>";
} else {
    echo "Error: Message not sent";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
     $to = "my-email@mail.com";
        $subject = "Survey";
        $name = "MyName";
        $from = "my-2nd-email@mail.com";
        $quest1 = $_POST['quest1'];
        $quest2 = $_POST['quest2'];
        $quest3 = $_POST['quest3'];
        $message = $quest1 . " " . $quest2 . " " . $quest3;
        $headers = "From:$from\r\n";
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers)){
        echo  "<h2>Your message is sent!</h2>
        <b>To:</b> $to
        <b>Subject: Survey</b> 
        <b>Svar:</b>
        $quest1'<BR>
        $quest2<BR>
        $quest3<BR>";
}
        else
        echo "Error: Message not sent";
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `"` in mail function after `$message` and made proper string in `echo` like this

```
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message)) 
   {
        echo '<h2>Your message is sent!</h2> 
                <b>To:</b> $to
                <b>Subject:Survey</b> 
                <b>Svar:</b>
                $quest1."<br>"
                $quest2."<br>"
                $quest3."<br>"';
    } 

   else 
    {
        echo "Error: Message not sent";
    }
```